# Loop 6 posts inside 3 li elements

Tags: php, wordpress, loops

How can I loop 6 posts inside 3 li elements. I want to tell my code to put 2 articles for every li element.

```
<ul class="seminar-list">
    <?php
        $args = array(
        'post_type' => 'topics',
        'posts_per_page' => 6,
        'tax_query' => array(
        array(
            'taxonomy' => 'topicscat',
            )
            )
        );

     $seminarQuery = new WP_Query($args);
     $idx = 1;
     if($seminarQuery->have_posts()): while($seminarQuery->have_posts()): $seminarQuery->the_post();
                        ?>
        <li>
            <a href="topicscat/seminar-info/#event<?php echo $idx ?>">
                <time><?php echo get_field('event-date') ?></time>
            <span class="location"><?php echo get_field('location') ?> 
            </span>
            </a>
        </li>
    <?php $idx++; endwhile; wp_reset_postdata(); endif; ?>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can bring the generation of the `<li>` tags into the PHP code, only starting an `<li>` on the 1st, 3rd, 5th... post and only closing on the 2nd, 4th, 6th...

```
 if($seminarQuery->have_posts()): while($seminarQuery->have_posts()): $seminarQuery->the_post();
    if ($idx % 2 == 1) echo "<li>";
                    ?>
        <a href="topicscat/seminar-info/#event<?php echo $idx ?>">
            <time><?php echo get_field('event-date') ?></time>
        <span class="location"><?php echo get_field('location') ?> 
        </span>
        </a>
<?php 
    if ($idx % 2 == 0) echo "</li>";
    $idx++; endwhile; wp_reset_postdata(); endif; ?>
```